# How to mirror the bars

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have two bars which I want to mirror. I have the following code

```
bar1 = df['nt'].value_counts().plot.barh()
bar2 = df1['nt'].value_counts().plot.barh()
bar1.set_xlim(bar1.get_xlim()[::-1])
# bar1.yaxis.tick_right()
```

But somehow not only the bar1 flips to the left(third line), but also the bar2. The same happening with the commented 4th line. Why is that? How to do it right then?

Comment: Well, `df...plot.barh()` doesn't return a bar nor a barplot. It returns the `ax` which indicates  the subplot where the barplot was added.  As both barplots are created onto the same subplot, `set_xlim` etc. will act on that same subplot. [This blogpost](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/algorithms-2017/classes/fuzziness-matplotlib/how-pandas-uses-matplotlib-plus-figures-axes-and-subplots/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df...plot.barh()`doesn't return bars nor a barplot. It returns the`ax`which indicates the subplot where the barplot was added. As both barplots are created onto the same subplot,`set_xlim` etc. will act on that same subplot. [This blogpost](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/algorithms-2017/classes/fuzziness-matplotlib/how-pandas-uses-matplotlib-plus-figures-axes-and-subplots/) might be helpful.

To get two barplots, one from the left and one from the right, you could create a "twin" y -axis and then drawing one bar plot using the lower x-axis and the other user the upper x-axis.  To make things clearer, the tick labels can be colored the same as the bars. To avoid overlapping bars, the x limits should be at least the maximum of the sum of the two `value_counts`.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'nt': np.random.choice([*'abcdefhij'], 50)})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'nt': np.random.choice([*'abcdefhij'], 50)})
max_sum_value_counts = df.append(df1).value_counts().max()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))

df['nt'].value_counts(sort=False).sort_index().plot.barh(ax=ax, color='purple')
ax.set_xlim(0, max_sum_value_counts + 1)
ax.tick_params(labelcolor='purple')

ax1 = ax.twiny()
df1['nt'].value_counts(sort=False).sort_index().plot.barh(ax=ax1, color='crimson')
ax1.set_xlim(max_sum_value_counts + 1, 0)
ax1.tick_params(labelcolor='crimson', labelright=True, labelleft=False)
ax1.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]